# How to tell Chromebook to say on a particular Wifi connection and not jump to another one unless it is told to do so?

Tags: wireless-networking, chromebook

I have two internet providers because I absolutely must have internet access for work, and both of our local choices for ISP have had problems over the years where each has been down for more than a week before the company got around to coming to the neighborhood to fix something out on the utility pole.  They each take a long time to escalate from "problem must be inside customer's house" to "problem is with our equipment on the utility pole".

My mobile phone's hotspot would be a third ISP option but the LTE and 5G signal from the tower is extremely weak in my neighborhood.

So now there's a choice of Wifi in the house.  Lately one of the Wifi connections has been flaky, so I've set my Chromebook to use the other, but the Chromebook keeps jumping back onto the flaky one of its own accord. I think because the signal is stronger on the flaky one. How to stop Chromebook from doing that? Is there another setting that tells Chromebook to obey the chosen Wifi setting?

I would prefer to not delete the flaky Wifi as it will probably get fixed in the next couple of days and then I will want to use it again.

Comment: You can delete it now and add it again later or is it so much inconvenience? Any sane person would think that it can't be more inconvenient than post a four paragraphs question, wait for who knows how long for an answer that likely will never come and if it comes it'll be along the lines of a very convoluted script. Is it only me or is this surreal AF?

Comment: @ChanganAuto I have other reasons for not wanting to delete the entry which I did not mention. I will have to retrieve the password for the Wifi from the back of the router, which is in a mess of dusty wires, and with the dust I risk having an asthma attack, even if I'm "suited up" in an N95 mask. There are so many damn wires from all of the devices (a couple of routers, TV, AppleTV, stereo receiver, CD/BlueRay player, etc), that it's impossible to keep the dust from building up on that bottom shelf.  So I just want to tell Chromebook to please obey my settings.